# Datatables AJAX call not updating table data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to update my datatable from an AJAX call using PHP. I have a drop down list when selected will filtr the data. The data is being retrieved correctly but the table is not updating based on this data.

When the page is loaded, the data is being displayed fine no problems, it only when I try an dfilter the data.

Below is the initialisation of the datatable and ajax call

```
var table = $('#business-page-click-through-report').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel'
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: Wo_Ajax_Requests_File() + '?f=filter_click_through_report',
            type: 'POST',
            "data": function ( data ) {
                data.filter = $('#history option:selected').val();
            }
        },
        serverSide: true,
        //processing: true,
        serverMethod: 'post',
        'columns': [
            {data: 'page_title'},
            {data: 'module'},
            {data: 'post_title'},
            {data: 'site_destination'},
            {data: 'totalClicks'},
        ]
    });
```

Next when an onchange event occurs the following code is executed:

```
$('#history').on('change', function() {
        table.draw();

    } );
```

I run the returned json data though a validator and it's all fine

```
{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 5,
"recordsFiltered": 5,
"aaData": [{
    "page_title": "Free Plan",
    "module": "jobs",
    "post_title": "Senior Web Developer \/ FUll Stack Developer",
    "site_destination": "https:\/\/www.seek.com.au\/job\/40560129?type=standard#searchRequestToken=c165897b-0be9-4734-84b1-040034173669",
    "totalClicks": "5"
}, {
    "page_title": "Gold Plan",
    "module": "jobs",
    "post_title": "gold plan test job",
    "site_destination": "http:\/\/www.google.com",
    "totalClicks": "1"
}, {
    "page_title": "Free Plan",
    "module": "products",
    "post_title": "fsdfsdfsd",
    "site_destination": "http:\/\/www.facebook.com",
    "totalClicks": "15"
}, {
    "page_title": "Free Plan",
    "module": "public-post",
    "post_title": "this is a public post for testing purposes",
    "site_destination": "\/read-blog\/381",
    "totalClicks": "2"
}, {
    "page_title": "Free Plan",
    "module": "events",
    "post_title": "this is an event for a business page",
    "site_destination": "\/car-shows\/this-is-an-event-for-a-business-page-3308",
    "totalClicks": "2"
}]
```

}

Not sure why the data is not being updated.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
Danny

Comment: does using `table.draw();` manually on the console results the same?

Comment: Hi @Shizukura, yes the result is the same

Comment: The ajax `data` property has to be a PlainObject or String or Array. You have a function there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have got a `cache` problem. `cache` is `true` by default.

Just try with the below code.

```
var table = $('#business-page-click-through-report').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel'
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: Wo_Ajax_Requests_File() + '?f=filter_click_through_report',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            "data": function ( data ) {
                data.filter = $('#history option:selected').val();
            }
        },            
        serverSide: true,
        //processing: true,
        serverMethod: 'post',
        'columns': [
            {data: 'page_title'},
            {data: 'module'},
            {data: 'post_title'},
            {data: 'site_destination'},
            {data: 'totalClicks'},
        ]
    });
```

After adding `cache: false` it should render your datatable with updated content.

**EDIT**
Try destroying the previous datatable before creating new one:

```
var table = $('#business-page-click-through-report').DataTable();
table.clear().destroy(); // If this doesn't work, remove .clear() and try table.destroy();
```

After this line run your actual datatable and ajax logic.

```
var table = $('#business-page-click-through-report').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel'
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: Wo_Ajax_Requests_File() + '?f=filter_click_through_report',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            "data": function ( data ) {
                data.filter = $('#history option:selected').val();
            }
        },            
        serverSide: true,
        //processing: true,
        serverMethod: 'post',
        'columns': [
            {data: 'page_title'},
            {data: 'module'},
            {data: 'post_title'},
            {data: 'site_destination'},
            {data: 'totalClicks'},
        ]
    });
```

Comment: My bad. previously I had added "cache: false" at wrong place. I have now edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Mayank thanks for your response but that didn't seem to chnage anything

Comment: Did you add it in ajax call? also, after adding it, remove "table.draw();" line.

Comment: Also, is your data structure same as needed?

Comment: Yes I did add it. If I remove the table.draw(); how does ajax get called?

Comment: Oh I get it. You are using table.draw(); for rendering again. Correct?

Comment: Please check my updated answer starting from **EDIT**

Comment: That seems to work just fine. Not an ideal solution but for the time being it's fine

Answer (score 0):

you can simply destroy the datatable, and initialise when the time of ajax call success.